# symfony2 custom login type

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am creating an application where users can use their mobile devices to order items off a menu. The requirement is that the users don't need an account (username or password) to access the service. The users will be authenticated via their ip and mac addresses.

So my question is how could I build this type of authentication into symfony? Keeping in mind that I want to still be able to use the regular firewall to secure urls for example:

```
 firewalls:
    client_area:
        pattern:    ^/client
```

I have searched google for an answer to this question to no avail.

Comment: How were you planning on getting the MAC address from the mobile device? And also: how would you coop with changing IP addresses?

Comment: The clients will all be on the same LAN so I will use arp -a ipAddress for the MAC address. Since I have the MAC if the IP address changes I can look up the device using it's MAC. Also the point of the question is how can I use other parameters (like IP and MAC) to login with symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a new Security by writing a new authentication provider.

Look at this cookbook entry on symfony.com. It's a very helpful thread about creating your own authentication mechanisms:

[How to create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)

In that example you see they use a HTTP X-WSSE header to authenticate. You could write your own provider which authenticate via IP or/and mac addresses.

Answer (score 0):

For using the IP, you can use built-in [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html). The example is for blacklisting, but you can adapt it for whitelisting. There is no further authentication needed, only a valid (specified) IP.

The list has to be specified in the configuration, but you could also generate that list dynamically, load it from a file, read it from a table, ...

If you want to use both IP and MAC address, you'll have to cook up something yourself. As far as I know, there is no built-in setting for that in Symfony2.

Comment: My question is not specifically on using the ip and mac address. My question is how I can use my own parameters to log a user in?